# Android Tablet - Download PDF and open it on browser

Tags: browser, pdf, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

Device - Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 / Android 4.0.3

I have tested Samgsung Galaxy Tab for document download such as PDF from web site with many browsers. Most of them just download it to somewhere in the device and I have to go to notification window(Right and bottom) and click it again to open it. Some browsers ask me to save and ask me again to open it.

Is there browser or a way that opens it when I download it? iPad works that way. iPad opens the file right away when I download a document.

Comment: I would say, for security reasons, NO. To have a browser just open a file that you downloaded, without asking you first, is a security risk. if you download an android app, it would open the "app installer" right away for the app. Or what if some other exploit was found that a file you download takes advantage of. If it opens it right away, you have no way to stop it.

Comment: All those documents are located in our server and they are all verified by us. We create only PDF and upload them on the server. So we do not need to worry about any security risk. Is there any way that we could try?

Comment: If your problem is specifically about having the android browser auto-open PDF files, I suggest changing the title of your question and adding tags about the browser and pdf.  Its not really specific to the Galaxy Tab, though it is probably worth mentioning the Android version you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [pdf.js](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/pdfjs/) extension for Firefox mobile ?

It's a bit slow and unstable for now, but it should work as expected.

Comment: That works beautifully. Thanks. That was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it without "replacing" parts of android. The file is not actually downloaded by the browser, it is downloaded by the Download Manager. You would have to set a "default" for PDF files (pdf reader) and then replace the Download Manager. Replacing download manager could be done, without a custom ROM, since it has "public" intent actions available that it fires when a download is completed.

If that is a viable option, [there is a question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974836/android-download-manager) that could be a starting point for replacing Download Manager with a custom one.

The iPad opens the file right away because there is nothing else you can do with it. There is no "available file system" on iOS. Where on android, you can save files, and even install a file manager to browse to them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between iPad and Android. I did not know the fact. I am not an Android developer, so I was looking for a way from changing Setting rather than programming. I hope there is a way to do it from setting.