# Open PDFs Automatically from Browser in Google Drive or Google PDF Viewer

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, pdf

Is it possible to configure Android to automatically open PDF links in an application such as Google Drive or Google PDF viewer instead of clicking link, then selecting the PDF from Notification bar.

The following question [Android Tablet - Download PDF and open it on browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26063/android-tablet-download-pdf-and-open-it-on-browser) is similar but the accepted answer with using pdf.js plugin in FireFox is a discontinued product.

We plan to deploy many Android tablets where users just use them to print PDFs, the default UI experience seems counter intuitive.

We just want user to select PDF in browser, open it, and select print; ideally replicating the simplicity of how iOS works for viewing / printing PDFs.

The tablet used in Galaxy Tab S2 running Android 6.0.1.

We cannot use Adobe Acrobat PDF viewer as the PDFs we need to print don't print correctly with Adobe PDF viewer.

Comment: Yes, it works but doesn't open from web links needs to download first as well. Adobe PDF reader can auto open from clicking links in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cloud Viewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/cloud-viewer/) add-on for Firefox opens PDF links without downloading the file.

> View PDF, DOC, XLS and PPT files without downloading them to your device. Save downloading time and space on your device. Here's how it works: Just before a compatible file starts to download, you are prompted to open the file in the Google Docs Viewer instead. If you choose to open in the online viewer, a new tab is opened and the viewer is loaded.

It does give the print option also but I haven't verified it. Tested on Firefox `55.0.2`, the latest on Play Store

On clicking a PDF link, you get a self explanatory dialog as below

[image]
[image]

Comment: On version 62.0.3, it says "This add-on is not available on your platform.
Not compatible with Firefox Quantum."